# Why wont datagridview show values?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview

I have a datagridview implemented in my code and my intention is to retrieve data from the database and return a dataset of that information... The code bellow gets the proper number of values but does not get the values or the icons(located in the bin). What could be the problem in this case?

```
    try
        {

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            ds = ce.getData("select  username, case statusOfUser when 't' then 'online.ico' else 'offline.ico' end as status from users;");

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn coluser = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            coluser.HeaderText = "Username";
            coluser.Name = "username";
            DataGridViewImageColumn colstatus = new DataGridViewImageColumn(true);
            colstatus.HeaderText = "Status";
            colstatus.Name = "status";
            dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(coluser, colstatus);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

this is all located within the form load of the program
the table in the database is:
username, password and statusofuser
status of user being 'f' or 't' to see if they are online or offline
the icons online.ico (for 't') and offline.ico (for 'f')are a going to be used instead of f and t

thank you

Comment: You set the datasource but you didn't bind it. dataGridView1.DataBind();

Comment: ah yes thank you!!!

Comment: though its: coluser.DataPropertyName = "username";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 
        coluser.Name = "username";
add 
        coluser.DataPropertyName = "username";
and after 
        colstatus.Name = "status";
add 
        colstatus.DataPropertyName = "status";